# php PharData Fatal Error

Tags: php, tar, gzip

I'm downloading a tar.gz file from aws onto my localmachine for now. I want to decompress it and unzip to read the contents. I'm getting an error when creating new PharData object with the file location:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message
'unable to create temporary file for decompression of gzipped phar archive 
"/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NB/admin/temp/ea975d07f1-response.tar.gz"' 
in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NB/admin/mcAdvanced.php:28 Stack trace: #0 
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NB/admin/mcAdvanced.php(28): 
PharData->__construct('./temp/ea975d07...') #1 {main} 
thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NB/admin/mcAdvanced.php on line 28
```

And my php code is:

```
file_put_contents("./temp/ea975d07f1-response.tar.gz", fopen($response_body_url, 'r'));
$phar = new PharData('./temp/ea975d07f1-response.tar.gz'); //Error here-line28
```

I think the permissions are correct. I am able to unzip and view manually. Anybody have any advice?

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot of directory/file]

Answer (score 0):

Your webserver needs to have write access to the Operating System's `$TEMP` directory in order to extract the PHAR file.

Use [`sys_get_temp_dir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php) to see what directory this is so you can apply the correct permissions.

Alternatively, you can specify a different directory to which your webserver already has access to use as PHP's temp dir.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue when using compression with phar archives that are beyond a trivial size.  The error originates from https://github.com/php/php-src/blob//ext/phar/phar.c#L2552 which seems to be triggered when `php_stream_fopen_tmpfile()` fails which is just an alias to [_php_stream_fopen_temporary_file](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d1764ca33018f1f2e4a05926c879c67ad4aa8da5/main/streams/plain_wrapper.c#L208).  Why this call is failing is not immediately clear. Using `sys_get_temp_dir` shows that temp is at `/tmp` which does have the correct permissions (1777) and plenty of space.

The workaround for this issue is to just not compress the archive.  I would argue that is not a very good answer, however, this is a long standing issue in phar and I wouldn't hold your breath for a near-term solution.